# AngularJS ng-modal do not return latest value from form input

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am still new towards AngularJS, I made a simple textarea to handle user input using angular model binding like below code (noted that my ng-app and ng-controller are being injected somewhere else but it is within the entire `<div></div>`):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="StatusCtrl">
//some other HTML
    <div class="sPTabs-holder">
        <tabset>
            <tab heading="Status">  
                <div>
                    <form class="statusPost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group no-margin">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 no-pad">
                                <textarea type="text" ng-model="inputStatus" class="statusPostBox" placeholder="what's new on your mind?"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group no-margin">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 no-pad">
                                <button style="width: 12%;" ng-click="postStatus()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Share</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </tab>

            <tab heading="Image">Image</tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
'use strict';
var Status = angular.module('Status',['ui.bootstrap','ngResource','ngSanitize'])
Status.controller('StatusCtrl', ['StatusService','$resource','$scope','$http', '$timeout', '$sce',
    function StatusCtrl(StatusService, $resource, $scope, $http, $timeout, $sce) {
        //Usable models
        $scope.inputStatus;

        //Html-bind
        $scope.makeTrust = function(html){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html); 
        }

        $scope.postStatus = function(){
            if ($scope.inputStatus == null){
                console.log('Blank post alert');
                alert('You cannot post with blank statuses!');
            }else{
                console.log($scope.inputStatus);
            }
        }
}]);
```

My problem is whenever I click on the submit button angular will always pop me with the empty input error even though I have input in the textarea. At first I thought that I made a mistake in my model binding so I have tried out to echo the value in html using `{{inputStatus}}`, things appeared as it was typed and also when I try to define a default value in `$scope.inputStatus = 'default value'`, the console does indeed echoed 'default value', but the problem is it doesn't store anything that is being typed in the form. What have i done wrong in my code?

Noted that I am not so familiar on how to setup AngularJS in JSFiddle. I apologize in advance if you would like to see the working demo.

**Update 1 - I have narrow down the problem, apparently the problem only occur when I am using angular tabs by [Angular Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). So what happen is if you revise the HTML code, there is this `<tabset>` section. When declaring the `ng-controller` after the `<tabset>` section and everything works like a charm but if you declare it before the `<tabset>` section, that is where everything mess up.

Comment: Tab is generating a child scope as I expected. You can use dot notation as suggested in my answer, or you can use $parent.inputStatus in your HTML (no guarantee for this approach, the main scope can be several level above, so multiple $parent is needed).

Comment: You can verify if it is generating a child scope by inspecting the generated HTML in your browser. If you see class="ng-scope", then it is generating a child scope.

Comment: @Icycool yes it is generating a child scope as you expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize `$scope.inputStatus` in your controller, otherwise it will pop out an alert windows if you haven't input anything in the textarea (which will initialize or update `$scope.inputStatus`).

So you change your controller to

```
$scope.inputStatus = "";
```

Then everything will work, here is a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/i9Io9BZuEXYQIYtWh1qr?p=preview).

## update

If you are using `<tabset>`, then you are facing [child scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) problem. `<tabset>` will create a child scope inside your controller, which means, the scope bind to `tabset` is the child of scope bind to `StatusCtrl`.

There are two ways to fix this problem. The first one is accessing the parent scope directly by changing your ngModel to below

```
<textarea type="text" ng-model="$parent.inputStatus" class="statusPostBox" placeholder="what's new on your mind?"></textarea>
```

The second one is easier but may looks like a trick, use `Dot notation` like @lcycook mentioned. In your controller `StatusCtrl`, declare a dictionary called `data`

```
$scope.data = {
    inputStatus: ""
};
```

Then you can access the `inputStatus` by `data.inputStatus` anywhere inside the controller scope and you don't need to care about the child scope.

Comment: But your fiddle works even if that line is commented out?

Comment: @icycool if that line is commented out, re run the demo, click the button, you'll get an alert window.

Comment: Yeah tried comment the line->stop->run->input text in textarea->submit. Text comes in console, no popup. If no text then there is popup.

Comment: Oh I found a bug, when you input something and delete it, then popup is not fired.

Comment: I suppose it's not a bug but a by-design. If input something then delete it, `$scope.inputStatus` is initialized, as we are comparing `inputStatus` with `null`, the condition expression is true. Now what we need to know, what's @kenny-yap 's expected behavior.

Comment: @Rebornix @Icycool both of you are almost to what i am expecting. My problem is the value in form input `ng-model="inputStatus"` is not being passed back to the script which in return when the code `if ($scope.inputStatus == null)` is being executed, it says that `inputStatus` is undefined therefore it is taken as null.

Comment: @KennyYap how about directly update my demo to reproduce the error you meet ? Then click save on the top of the page and share us the link.

Comment: @Rebornix i have found a cause with it and narrow down the problem. Pls see update 1 thanks.

Comment: @Rebornix @Icycool yes i am actually facing a child scope problem. Manage to fix it by using the dot notation. I am also trying the `$parent` approach but doesn't seem to work... Is it because there could be multiple parent involve in this scenario?

Comment: yup, it's possible. Since angular would create separate child scope silently sometimes, you should avoid use `$parent` which might break easily if you change the HTML layout. Forget my `$parent` suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

While there is no direct evidence, I suspect your text area is masked inside a child scope. This is common for new AngularJS developers.

While you are learning which directive creates a child scope (e.g. ng-if, ng-repeat), you can avoid this problem with "Dot notation". Which is, wrapping the model inside an object.

You can do this by initializing your ng-model or at least the wrapper object in your controller.

```
$scope.data = {};
// OR
$scope.data = {inputStatus=''};
```

Then in your template

```
<textarea type="text" ng-model="data.inputStatus" class="statusPostBox" placeholder="what's new on your mind?"></textarea>
```

Process it in your controller by referring it as `$scope.data.inputStatus`.

Some people even argue you are doing it wrong if you don't do this for any ng-model, but I find thinking wrapper object name is hard so I still use "dotless" one if I know the there is no child scope.